# Application page ~masterurl/default.master does not exist

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, custom-form, application-pages

I've created a master page that inherit from WebPartPage.
This page would replace the newform on a custom list.

When i browse the page i've the error:

```
The file '/_layouts/15/wsp.generateDocFromMetalist/~masterurl/default.master' does not exist.
```

Do you know how to solve this issue? (My application page is deployed under /layouts/wsp.feature/

Here is my aspx

```
    <%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Page Language="C#"  CodeBehind="newDOPForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="wsp.GenerateDocFromMetaList.Layouts.wsp.GenerateDocFromMetaList.newDOPForm" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" %>

<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:ListFormPageTitle runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
    <span class="die">
        <SharePoint:ListProperty Property="LinkTitle" runat="server" id="ID_LinkTitle"/>
    </span>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageImage" runat="server">
    <img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif?rev=23" width='1' height='1' alt="" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <div style="padding-left:5px">
    </ContentTemplate>
</SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
    <h1>..:: I Like SharePoint ::..</h1>
    <table class="ms-core-tableNoSpace" id="onetIDListForm">
     <tr>
      <td>
     <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="None" ID="Main" Title="loc:Main"><ZoneTemplate>
        </ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
<SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" ControlId="FormCustomRedirectControl" AllowMultipleControls="true"/>
    <SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
        <SharePoint:CssRegistration Name="forms.css" runat="server"/>
    </ContentTemplate></SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderTitleLeftBorder" runat="server">
<table cellpadding="0" height="100%" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
 <tr><td class="ms-areaseparatorleft"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif?rev=23" width='1' height='1' alt="" /></td></tr>
</table>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderTitleAreaClass" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript" id="onetidPageTitleAreaFrameScript">
    if (document.getElementById("onetidPageTitleAreaFrame") != null) {
        document.getElementById("onetidPageTitleAreaFrame").className = "ms-areaseparator";
    }
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderBodyAreaClass" runat="server">
<SharePoint:StyleBlock runat="server">
.ms-bodyareaframe {
    padding: 8px;
    border: none;
}
</SharePoint:StyleBlock>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderBodyLeftBorder" runat="server">
<div class='ms-areaseparatorleft'><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif?rev=23" width='8' height='100%' alt="" /></div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderTitleRightMargin" runat="server">
<div class='ms-areaseparatorright'><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif?rev=23" width='8' height='100%' alt="" /></div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderBodyRightMargin" runat="server">
<div class='ms-areaseparatorright'><img src="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif?rev=23" width='8' height='100%' alt="" /></div>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderTitleAreaSeparator" runat="server"/>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Use `DynamicMasterPageFile` instead of `MasterPageFile`:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"  CodeBehind="newDOPForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="wsp.GenerateDocFromMetaList.Layouts.wsp.GenerateDocFromMetaList.newDOPForm" DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" %>
```

Comment: i've tried this and have error: Error parsing attribute 'dynamicmasterpagefile': Type 'wsp.GenerateDocFromMetaList.Layouts.wsp.GenerateDocFromMetaList.newDOPForm' does not have a public property named 'dynamicmasterpagefile'.
My application page inherit from WebPartPage

Comment: Inheriting from `WebPartPage` is a strange thing for an applicative (_layouts) page... Why don't you inherit from `LayoutsPageBase`?

Comment: Because this page will be use form a list form. so in tutorial they explain that we've to inherit from WebPartPage. http://www.ilikesharepoint.de/2013/11/sharepoint-create-custom-list-forms-with-visual-studio-part-2/

Comment: i've tried with v4.master in place of default.master as i'm in SharePoint 2013 but still have error

Comment: List form or not, an applicative page inherits from `LayoutsPageBase` (or `UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase`). You definitely can you an applicative page as a New/Display/Edit form.

Comment: Do you have sample for SP2013 on how to create custom form? I've to add javascript and some other control on new and edit form

Answer (score 0):

I use this in `aspx` and the error disappeared

```
MasterPageFile="~/_layouts/default.master"
```